# Twitter bootstrap not scrolling in mobile devices

Tags: mobile, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

Looking for a bit of help.

I'm using Bootstrap, everything looking okay, where it should be at least in browser (Chrome OSX) even when i resize to mobile and phone sizes but when i load it up on my iPhone in safari and chrome it doesn't scroll and my nav doesn't collapse.

213.229.64.160 - **Wouldn't let me link this.**

Anyone that could shed a bit of light on my problem i with be very greatful.

Thanks
Rg.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem using Durandal for my SPA framework. After lots of digging I found:

- The issue is related to the Durandal App module (if you're using Durandal!)
- [This Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618836/bootstrap-no-scrollbars-on-ios) is what tipped me off
- A bit more information about `app.adaptToDevice()` in the [Durandal Docs](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/App/)
- A discussion of the bug [here](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/issues/117).

Ultimately like the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618836/bootstrap-no-scrollbars-on-ios) I referenced above, I had to disable the call to

```
document.ontouchmove = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

I still have lots of digging to do to figure out *why* all this happens, but hopefully this helps.